# Is it legal to use a search engine programatically using cURL?

Tags: curl, search-engine, scrape

I want to make a search request to Bing using cURL and use the search results. Is it against their terms of service? If so would you please post the URL where is says that. I could not find one.

Comment: This is not the place for legal advice. Contact them directly if you are unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here are the terms:
http://explore.live.com/microsoft-service-agreement?ref=none&mkt=en-us

bing offers search results as rss:
http://www.bing.com/search?q=stackoverflow&format=rss

so they 'want' that you fetch their results. but it depends, what you want to do with it. just reading? or maybe formatting ... presenting ... publishing ... that could be more difficult.